# Express only redirect to desired page when successRedirect exists in passport.authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I got some issues with a Node Express app. It will not redirect when I removed successRedirect property in auth method by passport.

The code below will not redirect to the desired page if I removed the successRedirect, and replacing it with a callback funtction.

The default code from defaultController.js

```js
// passport local strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passReqToCallback: true,
}, (req, email, password, done)=>{
    User.findOne({ email:email }).then(user=>{
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error-message', 'User not found with this email.'));
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, passwordMatched)=>{
            if(err){
                return err;
            }
            if(!passwordMatched){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error-message', 'Invalid username or password.'));
            }
            return done(null, user, req.flash('success-message', 'Login successful'));
        });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

router.route('/login')
    .get(defaultController.login)
    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/admin',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true,
        successFlash: true,
        session:true,
    }), defaultController.loginPost);
```

And this is what I would like to apply, but it seems it won't work and stuck in a infinite loading on chrome, however on console, it can receive an output:
[here’s the output from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L66Ts.png)

```js
router.route('/login')
.get(defaultController.login)
.post(passport.authenticate('local', {
    // successRedirect: '/admin',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
    successFlash: true,
    session:true,
}), (user)=>{
    console.log(user.user.role);
    if(user.user.role === 'admin'){
        defaultController.loginPost;
    }else{
        console.log('hi');
    }
});
```

As additional information, here is snippets defaultController that is responsible for handling the request:

```js
login: (req,res)=>{
        console.log();
        res.render('default/login')
    },
    loginPost: (req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body.username);
        res.render('/admin')
    },
```

Any help?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `redirect` instead of `render` so do like this:

```
login: (req,res)=>{
        console.log();
        res.redirect('default/login')
    },
    loginPost: (req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body.username);
        res.redirect('/admin')
    },
```